# Comparing the rows of two pandas data frames by the column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames which represent data pulled from two different pedometers that record how many miles a given person ran for a specific month.

I want to calculate the difference in "Miles Run" for rows in DF 1 and DF 2 which have the same "Month of Year" **and** "Person". For example, DF 1 and DF 2 have the miles Joe ran in January and the miles Bob ran in February. For both of these common rows, I want to calculate how different "Miles Run" is for both.

Any idea how to pull out rows from two DF's that have 2 matching column values?

DF 1:

```
Month of Year   Miles Run   Person 
   January      6.7458      Joe 
   February     1.3808      Bob
   March        11.2689     Jill  
   April        9.8917      Sarah
```

DF 2:

```
Month of Year   Miles Run   Person 
   November     5.5234      Andrew 
   December     7.4523      Kyle
   January      9.1189      Joe  
   February     7.4343      Bob
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set_index` and let Pandas use intrinsic data alignment to perform subtraction:

```
(DF1.set_index(['Month of Year','Person']) - DF2.set_index(['Month of Year','Person'])).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
                      Miles Run
Month of Year Person           
April         Sarah      0.0000
December      Kyle       0.0000
February      Bob       -6.0535
January       Joe       -2.3731
March         Jill       0.0000
November      Andrew     0.0000
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks